# How come this button is not on the same line as the one next to it?

Tags: html, css

I have a weird situation in that if a button has more than one line of text in it, it puts it out of alignment with the one next to it. I can't figure it out.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/je821vz9/21/

```css
body {
    width: 400px;
}

.prompt-gate {
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 background-color: #fefab1;
 border: 1px solid #ffd532;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.prompt-gate-button {
 background-color: #0E80B4;
 color: white;
 font-size: 12px;
 height: 60px;
 width: 72px;
 border: none;
 margin: 15px 25px;
 outline: none;
 font-style: normal;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.pg-3-buttons {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.pg-sp2 button {
 margin: 5px 15px;
 width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="varied-width">
    <div class="pg-sp2 prompt-gate">Did you find what you were looking for?
        <div class="pg-3-buttons">
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(1)">Yes</button>
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(0)">No, no no nono, no, no no.</button>
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(2)">No, I need help.</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why on earth is the top-right button moved down a few pixels? When you make the text of the button shorter, e.g. "some text" it goes back to the correct position. **WHY?** How do I make it stay in the correct place with longer text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your buttons are display `inline-block`.
By default inline-block elements are aligned to the baseline of its parent, which means that the taller one of the elements is, the more out of line it will look.
To solve this, use `vertical-align`:

```
.prompt-gate-button {
    background-color: #0E80B4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 72px;
    border: none;
    margin: 15px 25px;
    outline: none;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrsebajq/)

Comment: thank you "Jesus Gray", I have been applying random styles for like an hour and didn't think of this one

Comment: No problem :P glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Because the buttons are inline style elements, and the default value for [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is `baseline`. Just set `vertical-align: middle;` to the buttons and you won't have a problem.

```css
body {
    width: 400px;
}

.prompt-gate {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #fefab1;
    border: 1px solid #ffd532;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.prompt-gate-button {
    background-color: #0E80B4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 72px;
    border: none;
    margin: 15px 25px;
    outline: none;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.pg-3-buttons {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.pg-sp2 button {
    margin: 5px 15px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="varied-width">
    <div class="pg-sp2 prompt-gate">Did you find what you were looking for?
        <div class="pg-3-buttons">
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(1)">Yes</button>
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(0)">No, no no nono, no, no no.</button>
            <button class="prompt-gate-button" onclick="PromptGate_sp2(2)">No, I need help.</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "top" and "middle both work it seems, is there a difference?

Comment: No, but if one expands past the set width then its siblings will align to its middle with middle or its top with top.